How do I interpret the Content-Type requirements for AWS4 Authorization Signature
I'm receiving an error while testing my signing my transmission via AWS4 and testing posting the transmission to a third-party telling me my Signature does not match with what the destination expects.
I am adding the Content of the HttpRequestMessage through the following code.  It is the string representation of the XmlDocument using ToString().
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("--mimeboundary")
{
    { new StringContent(XmlLoader.ManifestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data"),"manifest" },
    {new StringContent(XmlLoader.TransmissionContent, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data"),"transmission" }
};

======================
Rules from the third-party are as follows:


Transmissions are encoded as multipart/form-data and must:

Include a Content-Type Header with the value multipart/form-data; boundary must be included.




I assume this means in the Header of my transmission I need to include multipart/form-data; boundary=mimeboundary
Q: Should this be done as part of the HttpClient or the HttpRequestMessage?
Adding this to the HttpRequestMessage gives me an error message.  I also receive the error message when I add it to the HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.

Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'

======================


Have a field named manifest with an embedded XML Document that complies with the TransmissionManifest.xsd.
Have a field named transmission with an embedded XML Document that complies with the FormTransmission.xsd.


I believe that my MultipartFormDataContent posted above does this.

The boundary is part of the Content-Type header. It needs to be
excluded from the Authorization Header signature calculation.

Q: Is this the SignedHeaders portion of the AWS4 Signature?

The Content-Type header must be multipart/form-data without the boundary
for the signature calculation.

Q: Does this contradict the bullet-point above when regarding the Content-Type header?
